# Animation take place during drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have an element that is draggable using jQuery UI's `.draggable()`, but I want it to follow a certain path while dragging.

In fact, while it is being dragged the whole layout of the page will be changing.

Since I have one set of styles for how the page looks like before the drag and one set of styles of how the page looks like after the drag is done, I figured using a CSS animation would make sense.

So, now, my question is how can I make that animation occur as the drag is happening?

Or if there is another way to do this then an animation, how can I transition from one style to another as a drag is happening.

What I'm trying to do is get the draggable element to drag into its place in the second styles.

Comment: Add a class `dragging` to the element when you drag and stylize it with css...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos That will just style it once. I need it to be gradually styled as the drag is happening.

Comment: Then you'll not do this with CSS, you may have to use jQuery animations component to do so...